# Extracting Logs by iterating through text files using PHP

Tags: php, file, loops, logging, phpexcel

I have a script that extracts logs and prints them into Excel file using PHPExcel, Each day of date is in each separate files, fo eg(2013-03-01.txt). Right now I am able to extract logs and print some actions and action counts such as(search, prints, emails, etc) but the action and counts are for a whole month period. I want to extract logs and get data based on single day such as action counts of searches, prints, emails in each single day. So what I would want to do is extract data from each file(2013-01-01.txt, 2013-01-02.txt) and print the actions data for each day. I hope I am being clear enough and here is the part of the code that extracts and prints data for a whole month:

```
     foreach ($files as $filename)
{
    $path = "$root/../request_archive/$filename";
    $extracted = "$root/../request_archive/$filename.temp";

    $fh = fopen($extracted, "r");
    $count = 0;
    while (!feof($fh))
    {
        $line = fgets($fh);
        if (preg_match("/^\[id\]/", $line))
        {
            $count = 0;
            $record = $line;
        } else {
            $count++;
            $record .= $line;
            if ($count > 1)
            {
                // echo "count: $count\n";
                // echo "\n\n$record\n\n";
            }
            preg_match("/customer: (.*?)(,|\s\[)/i", $record, $regs);
            if (!isset($regs[1]) || $customer_name != $regs[1])
            {
                preg_match("/client: (.*?),/i", $record, $regs);
                if (!isset($regs[1]) || $customer_name != $regs[1])
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            preg_match("/\[command\] (.*?) \[/i", $record, $regs);
            $log_command = $regs[1];
            preg_match("/\[params\] (.*?) \[/i", $record, $regs);
            $content = $regs[1];
            //preg_match("/\[request_time\] (.*?) \[/i", $record, $regs);
            preg_match("/\[request_time\] (.*?) /", $record, $regs);

            $request_time = $regs[1];
            echo "request_time: $request_time\n";
            $request_ts = strtotime($request_time);

            if ($start_ts && $start_ts > $request_ts)
                continue;
            if ($end_ts && $end_ts < $request_ts)
                continue;

            $data = parse_command($log_command, $content);
            $command = $data['command'];
            $params = $data['params'];
            switch($command)
            {
                case 'venue search':
                    $actonCounts['venue search']++;
                    break;
                case 'event search':  
                    $actionCounts['event search']++;
                    break;
                case 'emails sent']:
                    $actionCounts['emails sent']++;
                    break;
            }       

            if ($command == 'skip')
                continue;

            $curr_row++;

            if ($save_to_excel)
            {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$curr_row.':C'.$curr_row)->getFont()->setSize(10);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$curr_row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_XLSX15);
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A'.$curr_row, $request_time)
                    ->setCellValue('B'.$curr_row, $command)
                    ->setCellValue('C'.$curr_row, $params)
                    ->setCellValue('D'.$curr_row, $actionCounts['venue search']
                    ->SetCellValue('E'.$curr_row, $actionCounts['event search']
                    ->setCellValue('F'.$curr_row, $actionCounts['emails sent'];

            }
            if ($save_to_csv)
            {
                $request = "$request_time\t$command\t$params\n";
                fwrite($fd, $request);
            }
        }

        $line = null;
        unset($line);
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: you should be inserting those records into a database. that'll make your querying MUCH easier.

Comment: @Marc, yes I am doing that but thats over a period of month, but now I want to extract it based on each day!

Comment: so? `where date_of_record='2013-06-25'` would pull up any records for just today. and `group by year(date_of_record), month(date_of_record), day(date_of_record)` and the like are also possible.